# working with existing SqlCe database in windowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sql-server-ce

I have a database named "mydatabase.sdf" which i made in a C# project. Now i want to use this database in windowsPhone. 
I just want to show data from the database in a list.
As i m new to windows phone i searched many times in Google but things seems complicated to me.
Now where to keep the database in wondowsphone project and how to show the data of mydabase.sdf in a list.
Can anyone tell me specifically??
Another question,is there any difference to use SqlCe in winPhone7 and Winphone8??
Can anyone help me???

Updated:
i used a tool named "ExportSqlCE.exe" to make a DataContext class for the sqlCe database and i just past the database and the DataContext  class in my project.
Method Definitions of My DataContext  class  looks like this:

```
 #region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnCreated();
#endregion

public System.Data.Linq.Table<Tbl> Tbls
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Tbl>();
    }
}
}

 [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="tbl")]
public partial class Tbl
 {

private string _Clm;

public Tbl()
{
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="clm", Storage="_Clm", DbType="NVarChar(100)")]
public string Clm
{
    get
    {
        return this._Clm;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Clm != value))
        {
            this._Clm = value;
        }
    }
}
  }
  #pragma warning restore 1591
```

My database has a table named "tbl" and one column named "clm".
i just want to show the column data of my table. I used following codes:

```
      register_dbContext db=null;
      .....

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

       // MessageBox.Show("hgf");

        using (db = new register_dbContext(register_dbContext.ConnectionString))
        {
           db.CreateIfNotExists();  
           db.LogDebug = true;
        }


        if (db!=null)
        {

            var contacts = from m in db.Tbls select m;


            foreach (var a in contacts)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(a.Clm);
                MessageBox.Show("fdf");

            }


            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
            // Use the connecton here...

    }
```

it shows this error:

```
Can not access a disposed object.
Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.
```

How can i do this??

Comment: No diff between Phone 7.5 and 8. I have some tips here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/01/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html

Comment: I have successfully connected the database but i dont know how to use these database.Means dont know how to fetch the data by making query from the database and show them in my app. If there is a details tutorial then it would be very helpful. @ErikEJ

Comment: Look at the MSDN links here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/07/windows-phone-sql-server-compact.html

Comment: Cant i use query as "select cloumn1 from table" ???previously  i used sql query in a C# project. @ErikEJ

Comment: No, only LINQ to SQL, as the documentation states

Comment: there are many documents here.Could u tell me  Which one is exactly ?? @ErikEJ

Comment: Look at the MSDN links!

Comment: Please see my updated question. i faced some problems.  @ErikEJ

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41765/discussion-between-new-and-erikej)

Comment: @ErikEJ please i couldn't understand what and how to do. I am stack with this for a long time. Could you help me?

Comment: you are trying to use db variable after you disposed it. When you wrap something in using(var obj = new Obj()){ } the obj is disposed after using statement ends.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the using-statement, which disposes the object at the closing curly brace. That is why you get that exception. All db access needs to be within the curly braces of the using-statement.

Change your code that way to retrieve your objects:

```
using (db = new register_dbContext(register_dbContext.ConnectionString))
{
           db.CreateIfNotExists();  
           db.LogDebug = true;


            var contacts = from m in db.Tbls select m;


            foreach (var a in contacts)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(a.Clm);
                MessageBox.Show("fdf");

            }


            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```